# Arquillian Persistence Extension with Spring and Javaconfig

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, persistence, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to use `arquillian-persistence-dbunit` where I have to seed the database with datas but none of my solutions work. My project is based on Spring and we are using JavaConfig.

In my POM, I have the arquillian jars :

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

 <!-- Arquillian dependencies -->
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-service-integration-spring-inject</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-service-integration-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
    </dependency>
```

My test class :

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@Transactional(PersistanceTestConfig.TRANSACTION_NAME)
@SpringAnnotationConfiguration(classes = {ArquillianConfiguration.class})
@DataSource(PersistanceTestConfig.MY_DATASOURCE)
@UsingDataSet({"database/myDataset.yml"})
public class MyTestClass{

      @Deployment(testable = false)
      public static WebArchive createArchive(){
          //returns a webArchive
      }

      @Test
      public void myTestMethod(){
        //do something
      }
}
```

My config classes :

```
@Configuration
@Import({PersistanceTestConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.dao", ""com.myapp.services"})
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ArquillianConfiguration {}
```

And the PersistenceTestConfig :

```
public class PersistanceTestConfig {
 public static final String TRANSACTION_NAME = "transaction";
 public static final String MY_DATASOURCE = "datasource";

 private Properties getJPAProperties() {
    final Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");

    return jpaProperties;
}


    @Bean(name = MY_DATASOURCE)
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
      return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .continueOnError(false).ignoreFailedDrops(true).build();
    }


@Bean
@Autowired
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerREFCS( DataSource dataSource) {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.myapp.dao.beans");
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("pUnitName");
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getJPAProperties());
    return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
}        
}
```

I have tried many solutions, but I still have the same error : 
`org.jboss.arquillian.transaction.impl.lifecycle.TransactionProviderNotFoundException: Transaction provider for given test case has not been found.`

What bothers me is there are not so many documentations on how to use `arquillian-persistence-dbunit` with JavaConfig. The only example that I see are badsed on xml configuration only. For instance, in this [project](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-spring/blob/master/arquillian-service-integration-spring-3-int-tests/src/test/java/org/jboss/arquillian/spring/testsuite/test/JpaEmployeeRepositoryTestCase.java).

Has Anyone used `arquillian-persistence-dbunit` with JavaConfig.

Comment: `JavaConfig` used in your example is for Spring framework, and since APE (Arquillian Persistence Extension) is "framework agnostic" we obviously don't have this functionality available - hence no documentation for that. Configuration is done like for all the other arquillian features/extensions. If you feel like it will greatly simplify your setup feel free to open an issue on GitHub and we could hack on this together :)

Comment: Thx for your reply @bartosz.majsak, I will open an issue to Github and would be glad to hack together.